# Is Madame K dead?

Tags: doctor-who, timeline

I know Amy killed Madame K in *The Wedding of River Song* (Season 6 Episode 13). But that took place in an alternate timeline. On the hand, at the end of that episode Amy is drinking wine because she is and she tells River

> "I killed someone, Madame K."

however right after that River replies

> "In an aborted timeline, in a world that never was."

So which is it, did she kill her or does it not matter because it was in an aborted timeline?

Comment: This is Doctor Who. Nobody is ever definitively dead. Even if it wasn't an alternate timeline, the Daleks have come back from total destruction more times than I can count.

Comment: Nobody is dead unless the show producer and/or actor playing the Doctor has changed since their death. :)

Comment: Even that doesn't help re: The Master

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Amy killed someone.  That person was an aborted timeline version of Madame K.  The real world version of Madame K is still out there alive.

However given Amy has the memory and psychological impacts of the death, I would take the view that Amy is now a killer despite River's reassurances.

Answer (score 2):

Amy is unusual in that her character can remember things that occur in alternate universes/time lines. The Doctor once referred to this as the result of growing up next to the crack in the universe. The best example of this I can think of that was overlooked was in "The Girl Who Waited" (Season 6 Episode 10): after her older self had been locked out of the Tardis to face certain death, Amy wakes up and says, "Where is she?"
SO: Madam K was not killed in Any's current time line but presumably must exist (because River remains twisted) but Amy can remember having killed her in another.